# Entroware laptop with Ubuntu 17.04 stopped outputting to HDMI

Tags: 17.04, hdmi

HDMI used to work on my laptop, but now neither the Sound nor the Display programs can see that my HDMI cable is connected. My sound card is `HDA Intel PCH` according to `alsamixer`, and my GPU is an nVidia GTX. The cable still works on my PS3. This has happened once before.

---

Just tried out different GPU drivers. I think I started with 378.13 from nVidia (which it falsely claims is open source, wtf!) and then tried the later version 381.22, and then tried the open source Nouveau driver. Rebooted each time and it didn't fix it.

Since the sound part of HDMI isn't working either, I'm thinking that it's not a problem with the GPU.

---

Tried installing a different nVidia driver (375.82), and when I rebooted, it was outputting to my TV until I logged in. Now I can't get it to output to my TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I did was install a different driver (the nVidia 375.82 one), and then I toggled some things in the `Display Settings` program, and it worked.

General advice is try different drivers.

Comment: Great! I suggest you talk more details about "toggled some things", it will be useful for many people that have painful headaches about NVIDIA drivers.